# How to COUNT for 3 consecutive months or more from a Date column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, correlated-subquery

[image: Click here for Small Sample Data for reference]

I'm trying to have my query COUNT the number of user rows but have 3 + months of consecutive data (aka rows passed). I was wonder how can you determine from a date column if whether or not an Employee passed 3 consecutive months or more of data/rows in the table?

I've tried using COUNT function and attempting to use temp tables but wanted to see if there was a better way to count each user by their departments who pass 3 consecutive months or more?

[image: Output Data]

```
DECLARE @TotalUserCount AS INT
SELECT @TotalUserCount = COUNT(DISTINCT [User_ID])
FROM [dbo].[Employee_Monthly_Raw]

SELECT DISTINCT a.Department AS 'Dep', @TotalUserCount AS 'Total_User_Count'
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
    RTRIM(LTRIM([Department])) AS 'Dep',
    [User_ID] AS 'User_ID',
    COUNT(ALL @TotalUserCount) AS 'Total_User_Count',
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) AS 'Baseline',
    FROM [dbo].[Employee_Monthly_Raw]
    WHERE 
    [User_ID] IS NOT NULL

    GROUP BY [Dep],[User_ID]
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) >= '6') AS a

GROUP BY [Department]
ORDER BY [Department]
```

Expected results should pass a count of EEs (Group by their Department) in which they pass 3 months or more of data from the 'Date' column that is entered in the first of the month format (i.e. '01/01/2019')

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results!

Comment: You definitely need to provide some examples, because the wording of your question isn't clear at all.  Following these guidelines would help:   https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Gordon Linoff & Tab Alleman...Thank you for the feedback, I added a picture link in the beginning paragraph titled, "Click here for Sample Data for reference" and the output titled as 'Output Data'. I can add more context if need be.

Comment: Which three months?  Any three months?  Do you want one user counted multiple times for each three-month period?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any user that has passed 3-consecutive months, anytime. One user should not be counted multiple times, just once if they have been passed 3-consecutive months or more.

Comment: Do you want to split it up by quarters in a year? or just any consecutive 3 month of all times?

Comment: @Kelevra - Any consecutive 3-month of all times from the 'Date' column. So not using the GETDATE() but grabbing 3-consecutive months from the column in the table.

Comment: When you mean consecutive, does it mean that he showed up every day within 3 month period? or he might just show up 1 time a month? Can you give an example of USERID who passed the parameter of 3 consecutive month

Comment: @Kelevra Yeah sure, so user_id  469 has shown up 8-consecutive months. Even if the user showed up 3-months in a row, they're eligible to be counted. Whereas user_id 421 passed only twice, so they wouldn't  be part of the user count.

Comment: @Kelevra By consecutive, I mean in this way (by month) example: 06/01/2017, 07/01/2017, 08/01/2017.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to have the number of employee's that worked(or showed up in the sample table that you provided) for the past 3 month

So it will be something like this

```
Select Count(distinct UserID) as Number_of_Employees,
       Department
From [dbo].[Employee_Monthly_Raw]
Where datepart(month,Cast(Date as date)) = datepart(month,dateadd(month,-3,getdate()))
Group by Department
Order by Department
```

Answer (score 0):

If for each row, you want to know if there are three months with the same values, then you can use `lag()`:

```
select emr.*,
       (case when lag(month, 2) over (partition by user_id, department order by date) = dateadd(month, -2, date)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as three_month_flag
from Employee_Monthly_Raw emr;
```

I'm not sure what this has to do with the aggregation you have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

wrote my code as per the syntax of postgres SQL 9.5.0

try with the sample data given below.check this out!!
please check the inline comments for better understanding.

```
    /* creating the table with sample data(it contains name that have visitdata*/

    create Table TT (Name Varchar(1),VisitDate Date);
        Insert Into  TT select 'A','2017-01-05';                                          
        Insert Into  TT select 'A','2017-03-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'A','2017-04-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'A','2017-05-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'A','2017-08-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'B','2017-03-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'C','2017-01-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'C','2017-02-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'C','2017-04-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'D','2017-01-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'D','2017-02-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'D','2017-03-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'D','2017-06-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'B','2018-01-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'B','2018-02-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'B','2018-03-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'E','2018-01-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'E','2018-02-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'E','2018-03-05';
        Insert Into  TT select 'E','2018-06-05';
    /*first I have created the flag for consecutive months and used that flag to retrive the required data.  lag(),lead() are used to create the flag for consecutive months*/
    with temp as (

    select name,visitdate, 

    coalesce(lag(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate),lead(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate))check1,

    coalesce(lead(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate),lag(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate)) check2

    from TT 
    order by 1
    ), 

    t2 as (

    select name,
    case 

    when
     (DATE_PART('year', visitdate::date) - DATE_PART('year', check1::date)) * 12 +
                  (DATE_PART('month', visitdate::date) - DATE_PART('month', check1::date))=1 

    or 

    (DATE_PART('year', check2::date) - DATE_PART('year', visitdate::date)) * 12 +
                  (DATE_PART('month', check2::date) - DATE_PART('month', visitdate::date))=1 

     then 1 else 0  end as flag

     from temp)

/*flag=1 indicates the consecutive months and flag=0 indicates non consective months */
    select name ,count(1) from t2 where flag=1 
     group by name 
     having count(1)>=3;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.this is my first post so i missed the explanation part.Thanks again @Brian.